# c# Question about Events

Tags: c#, events

This is not so much a problem, just something that I would like to understand.

I have a function within a dll that returns a datagridview to a GUI call.  Within the dll file I have an eventhandler that monitors for a click within a certain area of the datagrid.  When I run this on the GUI using the returned Datagrid, the event still works.

I would have thought after the dll had returned the datagrid, it's resposibilities would have ended?  Or does the return also return all assocaited events?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you return is a *reference to the `DataGridView` instance*. If you have attached event listeners to that instance, no matter where, they will trigger when the events fire.